# Find the marginal densities of X and Y?

Tags: probability, statistics

The joint probability density function of X and Y is given by

[image]

Can somebody give me some clue on how to find the marginal densities of X and Y?

And what kind of distribution is this?

Comment: It is a [bivariate normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) (with correlation).  The marginal densities are what you might guess from the parameters.

Comment: To prove ^, you can integrate wrt y, this this needs some tricks